# formulas excel charts how to auto dynamic select last 5 value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

how do i change this rows formulas

```
=OFFSET(sheet1($B$3,COUNT(sheet1!$B:$B)0,5,1)
```

to become column show as image

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to do something similar to what is done [here](http://www.criticaltosuccess.com/dynamic-charts-in-excel-resize-with-offset-function-named-ranges/)?

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$3,,COUNT(Sheet1!$B$3:$XFD$3)-5,1,5)
```

It assumes no gaps in data.

And according to [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/average-last-5-values-in-columns)...you get around less than 5 at end with

```
=OFFSET(B3,0,COUNT(3:3)-MIN(5,COUNT(3:3)),1,MIN(5,COUNT(3:3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Tweaking the approach found [here](http://www.criticaltosuccess.com/dynamic-charts-in-excel-resize-with-offset-function-named-ranges/).

I created a named range for your labels:  `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$3,,COUNTA(Sheet1!$B$3:$XFD$3)-COUNTA(Sheet1!$B$3:$F$3),,COUNTA(Sheet1!$B$3:$F$3))`

And a similar one for your values: `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$4,,COUNTA(Sheet1!$B$4:$XFD$4)-COUNTA(Sheet1!$B$4:$F$4),,COUNTA(Sheet1!$B$4:$F$4))`.

And then edited my chart source data to refer to those named ranges.

Answer (score 0):

The column number containing the last number in row 3 can be obtained with,

```
=match(1e99, 3:3)
```

You can put together two index functions to represent a range like this,

```
=index(3:3, , match(1e99, 3:3)-4):index(3:3, , match(1e99, 3:3))  '<~~K3:O3
=index(2:2, , match(1e99, 3:3)-4):index(3:3, , match(1e99, 3:3))  '<~~K2:O3
```

This can be proofed with a simple sum operation.

```
=sum(index(3:3, , match(1e99, 3:3)-4):index(3:3, , match(1e99, 3:3)))
```

... which correctly returns 12 from your sample data.

You might want to use one of those formulas as the RefersTo: of a named range and use the named range in your chart definition.