# Change chart range with VBA

Tags: excel, dynamic, charts, range, vba

I want to move the range of a chart one column to the right each time I run the code. So minimum range moves one to the right and the maximum aswell, meaning the count is the same.

Example:
I have a chart with sales over the last 6 weeks in cell P13-U13, I only want to see the data for 6 weeks, so when I add new 7th week the chart should show the data in cell Q13-V13. (6 weeks in total)

I found this code, which add's one extra column to the chart each time it runs.
Meaning first time it runs it shows week 1-7, secound time 1-8, next 1-9 and I would like it to show 2-7, 3-8, 4-9 ect. 
My idea is to alter the code so the left side also moves one to the right. But I have not been able to get it to work yet.

```
Sub ChartRangeAdd()
On Error Resume Next
Dim oCht As Chart, aFormulaOld As Variant, aFormulaNew As Variant
Dim i As Long, s As Long
    Dim oRng As Range, sTmp As String, sBase As String

Set oCht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
oCht.Select
For s = 1 To oCht.SeriesCollection.count
    sTmp = oCht.SeriesCollection(s).Formula
    sBase = Split(sTmp, "(")(0) & "(<FORMULA>)" ' "=SERIES(" & "<FORMULA>)"
    sTmp = Split(sTmp, "(")(1) ' "..., ..., ...)"
    aFormulaOld = Split(Left(sTmp, Len(sTmp) - 1), ",") ' "..., ..., ..."
    aFormulaNew = Array()
    ReDim aFormulaNew(UBound(aFormulaOld))
    ' Process all series in the formula
    For i = 0 To UBound(aFormulaOld)
        Set oRng = Range(aFormulaOld(i))
        ' Attempt to put the value into Range, keep the same if it's not valid Range
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            Set oRng = oRng.Worksheet.Range(oRng, oRng.Offset(0, 1))
            aFormulaNew(i) = oRng.Worksheet.Name & "!" & oRng.Address
        Else
            aFormulaNew(i) = aFormulaOld(i)
            Err.Clear
        End If
    Next i
    sTmp = Replace(sBase, "<FORMULA>", Join(aFormulaNew, ","))
    Debug.Print "Series(" & s & ") from """ & oCht.SeriesCollection(s).Formula & """ to """ & sTmp & """"
    oCht.SeriesCollection(s).Formula = sTmp
    sTmp = ""
Next s
Set oCht = Nothing
End Sub
```

(LINK: [VBA: Modify chart data range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285577/vba-modify-chart-data-range/19287326#19287326))

Thank you!

Comment: This can be done with a dynamic chart - maybe some inspiration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50334792/formulas-excel-charts-how-to-auto-dynamic-select-last-5-value) or [here](http://www.criticaltosuccess.com/dynamic-charts-in-excel-resize-with-offset-function-named-ranges/), among others.

Comment: Hello BigBen. 


Thank you very much for the comment. 
However, I would like to have this function as a macro since it will have to be done multiple times in many differnet sheets. 


Regards 
Jonas

Comment: Ahh - I figured I'd throw the option out there, just in case the issue could be resolved simply.